# What does the period "." do in the find command in bash?

Tags: bash, find, command

I'm writing a small script to count all the files in a directory, and have a solution as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

I understand everything in this solution so far, except for the period after find. Why is it there, and what does it do? Why does the solution not work without it? E.g. why can't I just write:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: It means the current working directory, or folder in Windows term. The latter works with *GNU* `find(1)` but not on `*BSD`'s and others.

Comment: See the `find` man-page: _find  [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...] [expression]_ : The arguments preceeding the expression (i.e. `-type f` in your case) are the _starting points_, i.e. the directories where the search should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `find` command, first thing you should give are the directories (you may specify more than one) where the search will be made. `.` indicates the current working directory.

`-type f` : Look for **files**, not directories. 
`-maxdepth 1`: Descent at most 1 level in the directory tree.
`|` : Redirect output to another command
`wc -l` : Print the number of lines in a file

Comment: Correct, but should be ".... are the directories ...", because in the general case, there are more than one.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thanks, I didn't know we could specify more than one path to look at.

Comment: Surely, the 99.9% normal use case is just the current working directory...

Answer (score 0):

In each folder are 2 links "." and ".."
"." - current folder.
".." - parent folder